# Options not showing when using custom input in React-Bootstrap-TypeAhead

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I am using React-Bootstrap-TypeAhead's latest version in my React project. The main goal is to display the options menu when the user types. The menu is displayed when using the default input component but once I use the render input method for customization the options menu stops showing:

[working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-typeahead-async-pagination-example-forked-29h0if?file=/src/index.js)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { AsyncTypeahead } from 'react-bootstrap-typeahead';

/* example-start */
const BasicExample = ({ key, label }) => {
  const [singleSelections, setSingleSelections] = useState([]);
  const [multiSelections, setMultiSelections] = useState([]);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

  const PER_PAGE = 50;
  const SEARCH_URI = 'https://api.github.com/search/users';

  function makeAndHandleRequest(query, page = 1) {
    return fetch(`${SEARCH_URI}?q=${query}+in:login&page=${page}&per_page=50`)
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then(({ items, total_count }) => {
        /* eslint-disable-line camelcase */
        const options = items.map((i) => ({
          avatar_url: i.avatar_url,
          id: i.id,
          login: i.login,
        }));
        return { options, total_count };
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }

  const _handleInputChange = (query) => {
    setQuery(query);
  };

  const _handlePagination = (e, shownResults) => {
    const { query } = this.state;
    const cachedQuery = this._cache[query];

    // Don't make another request if:
    // - the cached results exceed the shown results
    // - we've already fetched all possible results
    if (cachedQuery.options.length > shownResults || cachedQuery.options.length === cachedQuery.total_count) {
      return;
    }

    setIsLoading(true);

    const page = cachedQuery.page + 1;

    makeAndHandleRequest(query, page).then((resp) => {
      const options = cachedQuery.options.concat(resp.options);
      // this._cache[query] = { ...cachedQuery, options, page };
      setIsLoading(false);
      setOptions(options);
    });
  };

  const _handleSearch = (query) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    makeAndHandleRequest(query).then((resp) => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      setOptions(resp?.options || []);
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <AsyncTypeahead
        {...{ query, isLoading, options }}
        id="async-pagination-example"
        labelKey="login"
        maxResults={PER_PAGE - 1}
        minLength={2}
        onInputChange={_handleInputChange}
        onPaginate={_handlePagination}
        onSearch={_handleSearch}
        renderInput={({ inputRef, referenceElementRef, ...inputProps }) => (
          <div className="form-group h-64">
            <label>Job Category</label>
            <div className="input-group">
              <input
                type="text"
                {...inputProps}
                ref={(input) => {
                  inputRef(input);
                  // referenceElementRef(input);
                }}
                className="form-control"
                placeholder=""
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
        paginate
        placeholder="Search for a Github user..."
        renderMenuItemChildren={(option) => (
          <div key={option.id}>
            <img
              alt={option.login}
              src={option.avatar_url}
              style={{
                height: '24px',
                marginRight: '10px',
                width: '24px',
              }}
            />
            <span>{option.login}</span>
          </div>
        )}
        useCache={false}
      />
    </>
  );
};
/* example-end */

export default BasicExample;
```

Comment: Why are you commenting out `referenceElementRef(input)`? That's what tells the menu to render relative to the input.

Comment: The version of the library I am currently using does not have this prop / not implemented.

Comment: What version are you using? Your sandbox uses the latest version.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the difference between the two versions, in fact I tried two versions with and without these props, so I am sure it is not causing the issue.

Comment: Oh, I understand your issue now. I thought it was literally that the menu was not being displayed, but it's actually that the fetched data doesn't get rendered within the menu.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not seeing any results rendered is that `_handleInputChange` is triggering a re-render and resetting the debounced `onSearch` handler before it can fire.

You can wrap `_handleSearch` with `useCallback` to fix that:

```
const _handleSearch = useCallback((query) => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  makeAndHandleRequest(query).then((resp) => {
    setIsLoading(false);
    setOptions(resp?.options || []);
  });
}, []);
```